# gedit on mac, change documents shortcut

Tags: macos, gedit

I'm using gedit on my macbook pro and the shortcut to change documents (tabs) within an editor is option+command+page up/down.

However, as it is a macbook pro, I find it slightly inconvenient to have to press the fn key + up/down arrow in order to make a page up/down input. Is there a way to configure the keyboard shortcut to be ctrl + tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly that you want to switch tabs by using ctrl + tab, you can do that with a plugin from http://live.gnome.org/Gedit/Plugins

Examples:

[Control Your Tabs](https://github.com/jefferyto/gedit-control-your-tabs) - Ctrl-Tab / Ctrl-Shift-Tab switch tabs in most recently used order.
Ctrl-PageUp / Ctrl-PageDown switch tabs in tabbar order.

TabPgUpDown - Switch between documents using Ctrl+PgUp and Ctrl+PgDown.

TabSwitch - Allows to ctrl+tab-switch between documents.

To install one of these, you need to download the files and put them in your ~/.gnome2/gedit/plugins/ directory (which may need to be created). They need to be in that exact directory; subdirectories are not scanned for plugins.